# Method chaining with nested method

Tags: coffeescript

I am new to coffeescript. However I didn't find any suitable word to put the question.

I have a coffeescript like this :

```
@collection.each (student) =>               
            ($(@el).find("#table .table").append new Item({model:student}).el)
                .find("td:last-child").hide()
```

However, is there any better way to do this method chaining than this ugly syntax ? I want to find the td:last-child from $(@el) only, without any brackets. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put the parentheses on the `append` to match the other function calls?

```
@collection.each (student) =>     
    $(@el).find("#table .table")
        .append(new Item(model: student).el)
        .find("td:last-child")
        .hide()
```

Comment: so in a manner I still have to put the brackets to differentiate between the Item and the find chaining right ?

Comment: @Joy: You're going to need parentheses somewhere if you want to chain.